# Java: How to add mapper for streamed items

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I currently have the following controller method (it's a bit simplified to only show the relevant part):

```java
    @PostMapping(...)
    ...
    public ResponseEntity<List<PresignedUrlsResponse>> getPresignedUrlBatch(@Valid @RequestBody PresignedUrlsRequest urlsRequest) {

        List<PresignedUrlsResponse> presignedUrlResponses = urlsRequest.getRequests().stream().map(request -> {
            // TODO: put this in it's own mapping
            String url = this.mediaService.getPresignedUrl(request.getObjectId(), request.getBucket());

            PresignedUrlsResponse response = new PresignedUrlsResponse();
            response.setId(request.getId());
            response.setUrl(url);
            return response;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(presignedUrlResponses);
    }
```

As mentioned in the TODO, I want to simplify this controller method and add a mapper. I'm only used to mapping requests from a db call for example (in which I will get a List of entities) but not when the service method has to be called for a list of items.
Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct supports mapping Stream to Collection and Stream to Stream.

However, in your use case you start with `List` and not with `Stream`.

You can move your entire logic in a mapper.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {
    PresignedUrlMappingService.class
})
public interface PresignedUrlsMapper {

    List<PresignedUrlsResponse> map(List<PresignedUrlsRequest> requests);

    @Mapping(target = "url", source = "request", qualifiedByName = "presignedUrl")
    PresignedUrlsResponse map(PresignedUrlsRequest request);
}
```

Your `PresignedUrlMappingService` can look like:

```
@Service
public class PresignedUrlMappingService {

    protected final MediaService mediaService;

    public PresignedUrlMappingService(MediaService mediaService) {
        this.mediaService = mediaService;
    }

    @Named("presignedUrl")
    public String presignedUrl(PresignedUrlsRequest request) {
        return this.mediaService.getPresignedUrl(request.getObjectId(), request.getBucket())
    }

}
```

and finally your controller method will look like:

```
    @PostMapping(...)
    ...
    public ResponseEntity<List<PresignedUrlsResponse>> getPresignedUrlBatch(@Valid @RequestBody PresignedUrlsRequest urlsRequest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(presignedUrlsMapper.map(urlsRequest.getRequests());
    }
```